# Downloading Certain Excel File and Interpreting Some of Its Values

Tags: java, eclipse, excel, apache-poi, jxl

So I'm working on getting a certain excel file, mostly a file that shows the assignments and grades that the students got on the assignments, and doing something with the values. Now, I want to get the assignment names, student names, student's grades on respective assignments, and date these assignments were due. The excel file is a little weird. The assignments are listed vertically and some assignments take up 2+ columns. I created a program in Java that tries to take the assignment names and values to put them in a scroll bar, but the assignments are listed very differently.

```
"Learning Experi
ST-2A: Life in "
```

This would be listed vertically in excel but when I read it in java this is what it shows:

```
    Learning Experi
    ST-2A: Life in
```

I want the output to show the above on one line.

Any ideas on how to tackle this problem? Thanks.

EDIT

Now when my program reads the excel file, there are some empty cells that it's reading. Here's the output of that:

```
Learning ExperiST-2A: Life in 
Learning ExperiST-2A: Life in 
[Empty Line]
[Empty Line]
Other information
```

How can I get rid of those empty lines that result from the empty cells my program is reading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by replacing the line separator by an empty String, like

`myString = myString.replaceAll(System.getProperty("line.separator"), "");`

You can check whether the line is empty or not by checking `myString.trim().isEmpty()`, and don't add it to your output if it is really empty.

Comment: Thanks that really helped! I edited my question because there's one more thing bugging me.